# What do I put in the first argument of `gsub` when used with a hash?

Tags: ruby, hash, gsub

You can use hashes in the second argument of `gsub`. All of the examples I've seen usually have something that I don't understand in the first argument, for [example](http://batsov.com/articles/2013/10/03/using-rubys-gsub-with-a-hash/):

```
def doctorize(string)
  string.gsub(/M(iste)?r/, 'Mister' => 'Doctor', 'Mr' => 'Dr')
end

doctorize('Mister Freeze') # => 'Doctor Freeze'
doctorize('Mr Smith')   # => 'Dr Smith'
```

If anyone can explain this, I appreciate it. Can anyone help?

Comment: As you can see in the example and is in the document, you put a regular expression as the first argument. What is not clear about it?

Comment: Thank you for helping with this. I think I need to start at square 1 and do research on regular expressions. To be honest, I didn't even know what that was. I'm not sure how to go about this, can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: Yep, a 'regular expression' is basically a pattern or template for matching a string. The slashes on either side indicate a regular expression object in ruby and many other languages. You can find lots of tutorials on regexes on the internet.  It's more typical with gsub to use a string as the second argument -- anything matched by the regular expression will be replaced by the string. Or a second arg that's a block with custom logic for replacement based on what was matched. I forgot a Hash even could be the second arg!

Comment: Just in case it's not clear from the other comments, if there is a match on the string `s` (e.g., `s => 'Mr.'`), `gsub` replaces `s` with `h[s]`, where `h` is the hash that is the second argument.

Answer (score 2):

The first argument is always just a regular expression. The Ruby docs on the [Regexp](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Regexp.html) have a pretty good explanation of regexes in Ruby. Or in general search for "regular expressions" or "regex".

In the linked article, the first is a "character class" (`[leto]` will match any single character `l`, `e`, `t`, or `o`) and the second is a "group" or "capture group" combined with a "0 or 1 time" quantifier (`(ister)` will match the string "ister" as a group, the `?` means this whole group may appear 0 or one times, thus the regular expression `M(ister)?r` will match either "Mister" or "Mr").

Comment: The first argument can be, and often is, a string. A non-capture group (`/M(?:iste)?r/`) would work as well, and really is preferred, since the value of the group is not used.